Img loading error | GLua | Garrys mod HUD
I can't add an image to my HUD in GLUA. I've tried to do it in the code, and I think it should work, but it doesn't. I have the correct type of image and its format.
Folders
hud
|---lua   
|   |---autorun      
|       |---client              
|           |---cl_hud.lua
|---materials     
|   |---gui          
|        |---add.png

cl_hud.lua
surface.CreateFont("HUDFont", {
    font = "Roboto Medium",
    size = 30,
    weight = 1200,
    antialias = true,
    shadow = true
})

hook.Add("HUDPaint", "CustomDarkRPHUD", function()
    local client = LocalPlayer()

    if not IsValid(client) then return end

    local health = client:Health()
    local armor = client:Armor()
    local maxArmor = 100
    local maxHealth = client:GetMaxHealth()
    local money = client:getDarkRPVar("money")
    local salary = client:getDarkRPVar("salary")
    local job = client:getDarkRPVar("job")
    local license = client:getDarkRPVar("HasGunlicense") and "Yes" or "No"
    local wanted = client:getDarkRPVar("wanted") and "In wanted" or "Not in wanted"
    local time = os.date("%H:%M:%S", os.time())

    local width = 350
    local height = 35

    --BG
    draw.RoundedBox(10, 20, ScrH() - 230, 400, 200, Color(100, 100, 100, 150))

    local iconMaterial = Material("gui/add.png", "noclamp smooth")
    if not iconMaterial:IsError() then
        surface.SetDrawColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
        surface.SetMaterial(iconMaterial)
        surface.DrawTexturedRect(20, ScrH() - 500, 20, 20)
    else
        print("IMG error!")
        print(iconMaterial) -- console log >> Material [___error]

    end
    -- HP bar
    local healthWidth = (health / maxHealth) * width
    draw.RoundedBox(8, 29, ScrH() - 80, healthWidth, height, Color(255, 0, 0, 220))

    -- AR bar
    local armorWidth = (armor / maxArmor) * width
    draw.RoundedBox(8, 29, ScrH() - 120, armorWidth, height, Color(58, 138, 219, 220))
    
    if armor == 0 then
        draw.SimpleText("HP: " .. health .. "%", "HUDFont", 32, ScrH() - 80, Color(255, 255, 255), 0)
        draw.SimpleText("Cash: " .. money .. "$" .. " | +".. salary .. "$", "HUDFont", 32, ScrH() - 120, Color(50, 200, 0), 0)
    else
        draw.SimpleText("HP: " .. health .. "%", "HUDFont", 32, ScrH() - 80, Color(255, 255, 255), 0)
        draw.SimpleText("Armor: " .. armor, "HUDFont", 32, ScrH() - 120, Color(255, 255, 255), 0)
        draw.SimpleText("Cash: " .. money .. "$" .. " | +".. salary .. "$", "HUDFont", 32, ScrH() - 155, Color(50, 200, 0), 0)
    end
end)

I don't know what to do because the HUDs I'm using can't load images. However, they are definitely working because when I download them, I saw screenshots of the pictures. But when I try to add them to the server, I see purple and black cubes instead.

If the HUD is showing the images as purple and black squares, that means your client can't find the image. As well as uploading the image to the server, do you also have a copy of the image in your game?
